Maxout activation function vs ReLU (Number of weights)
From what I understood, Maxout function works quite differently from ReLU.
ReLU function is max(0, x), so the input x is (W_T x + b)
Maxout function has many Ws, and it is max(W1_T x + b1, W2_T x + b2, ...)
I understood that The ReLU function does not have the perceptron's Weights in the funcion, but Maxout function has Weights in the function. (and has more parameters)
Did I understand right?
Many activation functions, such as ReLU, Sigmoid, tanh, Leaky ReLU works with scalar value, which is a already calculated value (W_T x + b)
Is is right that Maxout function is different from this?
So then from activation function's variation, can number of weights change?

Activation functions do not change the number of parameters of the neural network. They act as mimicking brain spike dynamics. In that sense maxout is not really an activation function but rather higher-order learnable part of the network architecture.
